# Custom R function exists in environment but where does it come from?

Tags: r, virtual-machine, rstudio-server

Taking over a project from a departed teammate.  They have an RStuido instance running in a Google Cloud VM with Linux. A script in the RStudio environment references `user_defined_function()`. The function runs perfectly fine, what baffles me is:

- The function is a custom function not imported from a public library.
- The function isn't defined in any R script (there is an `rtools.R` included, but the function isn't defined there and works if that script is sourced into the environment or not).
- It's not listed in my environment user defined functions.
- I when loading the same script into a different environment, I get an error saying `function not found`.

I'm assuming it's included somewhere in the VM environment, but I don't see any R script/files that live anywhere else in the VM, outside of the main R directory loaded by the instance of R Studio.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is there a ˋ.Rprofileˋ?  
https://rviews.rstudio.com/2017/04/19/r-for-enterprise-understanding-r-s-startup/

Comment: @margusl No.  However I figured out a solution that worked for my purposes, added.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I settled on:

Called `getAnywhere(user_defined_function)` to obtain the code of the function so I could re-create it elsewhere, it also revealed the library name (it was a custom team package I could get my hands on).

Comment: So the first thing that baffled you was just plain incorrect. I was going to ask which packages you had loaded and what environment the function is in.

Comment: @Dason fair enough.  Edited the question to reflect this.  What really happened was  a custom package that I didn't know existed had been installed on that VM.  Regardless hopefully the solution will help a "R foreigner" such as myself